# "NullReferenceException was unhandled" error occurring when accessing SourceControl through C#

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, source-control-explorer

Here is my piece of code through which I am trying to access the TFS Server SourceControl :

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://test-server:8080/tfs/CollectionName");
VersionControlServer sourceControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

RecursionType recursion = RecursionType.OneLevel;
Item[] items = null;
ItemSet itemSet = sourceControl.GetItems("$/Product/", recursion);
items = itemSet.Items;
```

But what I get is a null on `sourceControl` when I am debugging the code. My path to TFS Server is also correct, I am not getting the values in variable `sourceControl`

Comment: At which line you're getting the NullReferenceException?

Comment: ItemSet itemSet = sourceControl.GetItems("$/Product/", recursion);
@ElGauchooo This is the line on which I am getting that particular error.

Comment: @ElGauchooo THe MSDN Document also says that this API is now obsolete. Can it be an issue ?

Comment: Ofiris provided the correct answer. You will also be abe to see this while debugging - set a breakpoint at the very first line and always control what the calls return. The `GetService` call will return null.

Answer (score 1):

Your server can't be found:

`TeamFoundationServer.GetService` method returns `Null` if the service can't be found.

See: [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb136213.aspx)

Make sure the program can access the port (check firewall and try to `telnet` to `test-server:8080`)

Moreover, as suggested the comments, `TeamFoundationServer.EnsureAuthenticated` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.teamfoundationserver.ensureauthenticated.aspx), can help pointing out when the URI is not valid.

Comment: A `tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()` can help point out when a Team Project Collection URI is not valid.

Comment: @Ofiris I am able to access the server as I am able to get the ProjectNames which are there in the TFS Server. So I dont believe that the server is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing hard coded Tfs path try the following code which seraches all online TFS projects.

```
List<RegisteredProjectCollection> projectCollections = new List<RegisteredProjectCollection>((RegisteredTfsConnections.GetProjectCollections()));

        // filter down to only those collections that are currently on-line
        var onlineCollections =
            from collection in projectCollections
            where collection.Offline == false
            select collection;

        // fail if there are no registered collections that are currently on-line
        if (onlineCollections.Count() < 1)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: There are no on-line registered project collections");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        // find a project collection with at least one team project
        foreach (var registeredProjectCollection in onlineCollections)
        {
            var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(registeredProjectCollection);

            Workspace workspace = null;
            Boolean createdWorkspace = false;
            String newFolder = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

                var teamProjects = new List<TeamProject>(versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(false));
            //.......
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried using this piece of code, but here also the value of "versionControl" comes out to be null when debugging.
Can you please show me how to access the sourcecontrol ?

Comment: You can tryout the following link to have full control over version control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883959.aspx

Comment: In the above piece of code, versionControl returns null but can I still access the sourceControl Items ?

Comment: You will be getting NullReferenceException agian. What i am suspecting is your firewall may stopping you to connect can you check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

you try the following lines of code. Which will take you to the dialog window to select online TFS projects. If any online projects available inside, select the project and click on "Connect" button. If succeded then you should get the instance of VersionControlServer else
what ever system is responding to you is valid since you dont have any online projects to connect.

```
                 TfsTeamProjectCollection _tpc = null;
                 using (var picker = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.NoProject, false))
                 {
                     if (picker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                     {
                        _tpc = picker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
                     }

                     if (_tpc == null)
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show("Please select a team project.");
                         return;
                     }

                    var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)_tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
```

Comment: I tried doing this too.. But the same results came. The versionControl coming as bkank..